# Can't Get DIV to be visible in Javascript Listener event

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html

**Here is a snippet of HTML:**

```
<div id="deletegroup" class="modal-open" role="dialog" 
 style="display:none;">
```

**Here is code from the event Listener in Javascript:**

```
'onbtDeleteClick': function (e) {
     var modal = document.getElementById("deletegroup");
     modal.style.display = "block";      
     this.syncData("btDelete_Click");
 },
```

When my list page opens, there is a list of items and each row has a Trash Can to delete the row , if clicked.

The problem is when the Trash Can is clicked, the Listener event called 'onbtDeleteClick' should display the DIV which is a modal on an HTML page and DIV/modal is not getting rendered.

Any ideas are welcomed!

Comment: This is the DIV for the modal in the HTML:
<div id="deletegroup" class="modal-open" role="dialog" style="display:none;" >

Comment: how are you adding the event listener in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to get a div to show up on button click, make sure it has content or has a set width and height. Else, it won't show up.

Checkout this [working example](https://codepen.io/RaysOfTheSun/pen/BqpQqP).

```js
$(window).ready(()=>{
    $('#btn-open-modal').on('click', ()=>{
    $('#modal-1').toggleClass('hide');
  });
})
```

```css
#modal-1 {
  background-color:black;
  width : 50vw;
  height : 10vh;
  position: absolute
}

.hide {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="modal-1" class="modal-dialog hide">
</div>
<div class="content" id="content-1">
  <p> Sample Conten Here </p>
</div>
<br>
<input type="button" value ="open modal" id="btn-open-modal">
```

On the other hand, you can make use of [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/#live-demo) to handle your modal requirements. Additionally, if you're working with ASP.NET (since you have `C#` in the tags) and chose to use bootstrap, you can assign the attributes used by bootstrap's modals to an ASP button like so:

```
      <asp:Button ID="BtnDelete" runat="server" Text="..." CssClass="..."
              data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalExample" />
```

Otherwise, the ASP button control provided by .NET has an `OnClientClick` attribute where you can pass in some client-side javascript code to be called whenever the button is clicked. The regular HTML button has `onserverclick` :)